# Controlling time of agents to simulate RFID readers

Tags: netlogo, rfid

I would like to test a RadioFrequency IDentification, [RFID system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio-frequency_identification). and build it with Netlogo because each RFID reader could be represented by an agent. Readers could act independently or be exchanging data (for example number of tags read) among them.
Tags are passive and are activated backscattering the signal from the reader.

I have not much experience modeling with Netlogo and I have not found similar example models.

I would like to ask for help that will allow me to start the model. 
The first issue I have is how to represent the system. I have thought to create a network where nodes are of both types readers and tags. Posible communication among them could be a link.

A more difficult programming issue for me is how to code a reader to be active for a specific time (e.g. a maximum of 4 seconds) followed by inactive periods of 100 milliseconds. If another reader is in the proximities and both are active at the same time there will be a collision and they cannot read tags.

I would appreciate very much any help

Comment: Your question is very broad — too broad for Stack Overflow. I’d suggest taking this a step at a time — code something simple, anything at all that resembles a start at what you’re envisioning, and get it running. Keep a copy of that version, then to try to add one small feature that gets it a bit closer to your goal. Keep that version too. And so on. Any time you get stuck on something specific, you’ll have a specific question you can come here and ask, always showing your code and explaining where in the code your specific difficulty is.

Comment: @SethTisue Thank you. I agree with you. The question is too wide. I just want to ask how I could possible control the length (time) of periods of activity and inactivity of an agent. Can you help me?

Comment: @SethTisue I am going to open a new question for this.